# Load a dynamic java agent into a jvm from c++

Tags: java, c++

In java, you can load a dynamic agent using the attach api. How could you load a jar file into a jvm from c++ without using the JNI? To clarify, I don't want to compile the c++ to a dll and do the injection from that, I want to be able to load the jar into the virtual machine from a handle to the java process or something.